# Nth-term test for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2 \sqrt{n}} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2 \sqrt{n}} $ supposes to diverge. But when the nth-term test is applied to it, like the way it is done [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPrEY.png), the limit will approach 0 when n goes to infinity, from which it looks like it converges instead. So, what is wrong here?

Comment: The nth term test only works one way, in that if the limit is nonzero it diverges.  The test fails if the limit is zero.  That being said, it certainly appears to me that this this converges by the integral test.

Comment: @Paul WolframAlpha says it diverges by comparison test: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bn-%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D%7Bn%5E2+%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D+

Comment: At $n = 0$ you have a problem, you divide by $0$.

Comment: The sum starting at $n=0$ seems to be a typo.

Answer (score 2):

One has, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2 \sqrt{n}} = \frac{n^2-n}{n^2 \sqrt{n}\left( n+\sqrt{n}\right)} \sim \frac1{n^{3/2}}
$$ thus 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n-\sqrt{n}}{n^2 \sqrt{n}}
$$
is **convergent**.

Answer (score 1):

First you cannot start the sum from 0, and the series is convergent for a great reason Olivier Oloa provided !